# How to call external ERC20 token transfer function

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to transfer ERC20 token from another smart contract. For that I am following [this article](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/is-it-possible-to-call-the-erc20-approve-function-from-another-contract/2758/2). So I wrote the smart contract as following,

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.23 <0.6.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract SmartMatrix is IERC20 {
    IERC20 private _token;
    constructor(IERC20 token) public {
        _token = token;
    }
    function sendERC20TokeToDnividends(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {    
        _token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error while I try to deploy,

```
This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.
```

But I remove interface It deploys successfully.
For example, The following code works,

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.23 <0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract SmartMatrix is IERC20 {
    IERC20 private _token;
    constructor(IERC20 token) public {
        _token = token;
    }
    function sendERC20TokeToDnividends(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {    
        _token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Edited:
Removed inheritance and tried as the following and getting same error,

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.23 <0.6.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract SmartMatrix {
    IERC20 private _token;
    constructor(IERC20 token) public {
        _token = token;
    }
    function sendERC20TokeToDnividends(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {    
        _token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `is IERC20`.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you for responding. I tried removing `is IERC20`. but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove the inheritance. Now replace your constructor with this one:

```
constructor(address token) public {
    _token = IERC20(token);
}
```

Now in the constructor you have to pass the address of the deployed `IERC20` contract.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did the following but getting same error,
` pragma solidity >=0.4.23 <0.6.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract SmartMatrix {
    IERC20 private _token;
    constructor(address token) public {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }
    function sendERC20TokeToDnividends(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {    
        _token.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
}`

Comment: Did you remove ```is IERC20```? I told you, you don't need inheritance when dealing with interfaces.

Comment: Example: https://streamable.com/jn9qt2

Comment: Yes I removed `is IERC20`. But still I am getting same error. And I have updated smart contract in the question after removing `is IERC20`. And the link [https://streamable.com/jn9qt2] is not working.

Comment: I've no idea what you're doing, but my code works. I'm deploying the contract with no errors, copy my code and try again https://pastebin.com/hTKU7SMv . I'm using Remix to deploy and complier version is 5.17.